# no store is detected when using vuex in vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i'm using vuex 3.6.2 with vue2 and i'm trying to access my store but i'm not getting anything even if i check my vue dev tools console

this is how i use my store

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import order from "./modules/order";
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate";
Vue.use(Vuex)
Vue.config.devtools = true

export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  state: {
    status: '',

    user: {}
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {  
    order,
  }
})
```

this is my order.js

```
import axiosInstance from "../../helpers/axiosInstance";

const state = {
    products: [],
};

const getters = {
    allProducts: state => state.products,
};

const actions = {
    getProducts({
        commit
    }) {
        return axiosInstance
            .get('/products')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                let products = response.data;
                commit('SET_PRODUCTS', products);
                console.log(products);
                return products;
            })
            .catch(error => console.log('Failed to fetch products', error));
    },
};

const mutations = {
    SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
        state.products = products;
    },
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

if i use post man ,i get the request but don't seem to get it from vuex ,even if i console.log the data is doesn't display anything

this is my store ,nothing's there

[image]

Comment: Please add a reproduction on Stackblitz using a dummy API.

Comment: If the store wasn't detected you wouldn't be able to see that there is an `order` store with `products` state and `allProducts` getter in Vue Devtools, so the store is definitely detected, but it sounds like you're maybe not calling the action properly. Unfortunately, you haven't included that bit of code in your question.